# Azure Graph API is not responding

Tags: azure, async-await, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to call Azure Graph API to update the user details, I have verified the access to graph api from my Application in Azure. Below is my code

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateUserDetails(string userId, string requestString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("You must spectify a valid user Id", nameof(userId));
        }

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(requestString))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdConfig.Authority);
        var getAccessToken = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AzureAdConfig.GraphResourceId, new ClientCredential(AzureAdConfig.AppId, AzureAdConfig.AppKey));

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", getAccessToken.AccessToken);
        string url = AzureAdConfig.GraphResourceId + AzureAdConfig.Tenant + "/users/" + userId + "?" + AzureAdConfig.GraphVersion;

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("PATCH"), url);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", getAccessToken.AccessToken);

        request.Content = new StringContent(requestString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        return response;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you describe more clearly what you mean when you say "it does not respond"? Do you mean it the call to `await client.SendAsync() ` never returns?

Comment: While debugging, I put a break point on ` HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);` and press F10 it go to the next line , but it never goes to the next line of code even after 5minutes. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Sounds like an async await deadlock. If you have a call to .Result somewhere, it'll deadlock in certain situations. The easiest solution is to use async and await everywhere if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I removed .Result from the controller action method and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

According to my test, you can not get HttpResponseMessage with await client.SendAsync(request)  in  console application. You should use client.SendAsync(request).Result to get HttpResponseMessage. This my code.
static void  Main(string[] args)
        {

```
       Console.WriteLine( CallWebApiProtected("2778d832-402f-4bc2-aa28-0720c92947d5"));
        Console.Read();


    }



    static HttpResponseMessage CallWebApiProtected(string userId)
    {


        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/token"; //token endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/b29343ba-***/oauth2/token
        string resourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net/";
        string clientId = "6187f317-5f3c-447e-b0c4-1fd7c31ec14e";//your application id
        string clientkey = "q6e2d7xPwfa5rWHDCV5Tv/75wVkAnsinAcgF5FFkf7Y=";//your app key


        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientkey);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential).Result;


        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        // Specify values for the following required parameters
         queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
        // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
        var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/users/" +userId + "?" + queryString;

        Console.WriteLine(uri);
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            //request.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationResult.AccessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            return response;



        }
```

Its result as below.
[image]

Besides,you can  get HttpResponseMessage with await client.SendAsync(request) in web application. This my code.

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> About()
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await CallWebApiProtected("2778d832-402f-4bc2-aa28-0720c92947d5");

        ViewBag.Message = response;

        return View();
    }
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<HttpResponseMessage>  CallWebApiProtected(string userId)
    {


        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/oauth2/token"; //token endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/b29343ba-***/oauth2/token
        string resourceUri = "https://graph.windows.net/";
        string clientId = "6187f317-5f3c-447e-b0c4-1fd7c31ec14e";//your application id
        string clientkey = "q6e2d7xPwfa5rWHDCV5Tv/75wVkAnsinAcgF5FFkf7Y=";//your app key


        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientkey);
        AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientCredential).Result;
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);




        // Specify values for the following required parameters
        queryString["api-version"] = "1.6";
        // Specify values for path parameters (shown as {...})
        var uri = "https://graph.windows.net/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2a757fb/users/" + userId + "?" + queryString;

        Console.WriteLine(uri);
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            //request.Content = new StringContent(postBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authenticationResult.AccessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            return response;



        }


    }
```

Its result as below.
[image]

Comment: Console apps can use `async Task Main()` as the entry point, allowing usage of async functions just fine. No need to block with .Result. (though of course async Main is syntactic sugar and uses `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();`)